# Django testing in creating a user with email address which is from session input, assertRedirects is not working

Tags: python, django, redirect, testing

The user creation is using an email address as `USERNAME_FIELD` and it is extracted from session and save in the form `save()`. It seems it is not going further down to the redirection. How can I test the redirection in this case?

**tests.py:**

```
class RegistraionViewTest(TestCase):

    valid_data = {
        'email': 'good@day.com',
        'password1': 'test1234', 
    }

    kwargs = {
        'email': 'good@day.com'
    }

    def test_registration(self):
        response = self.client.post(reverse('registration'), data=self.valid_data, follow=True)
        self.assertTrue(response.context['form'].is_valid())

        # mocking the session input
        response.context['form'].save(email=self.kwargs['email'])
        self.assertTrue(account.check_password(self.valid_data['password1']))

        # working so far, but it seems there is no redirect url in response
        self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('next_url'))
```

**In views.py:**

```
   if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegistraionForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():   
        email = request.session.get('email') 
        try: 
            account = form.save(email=email)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('next_url'))
```

**In forms.py:**

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
    user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.email = kwargs.pop('email')
    user.save()
    return user
```

It seems there is no url in the response in `tests.py`. What went wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response may be a 500, not a 302, which would mean there is no Location header.

The call for request.session.get('email') will likely throw a KeyError, as your test does not appear to set the session['email'] field, and there is no default.

Note that when using a session in a test case, you need to assign it to a variable in the beginning, as in the example below (from [Django Testing Tool docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.session)):

```
def test_registration(self):
    session = self.client.session
    session['email'] = self.kwargs['email']
    session.save()
    # and now make your call to self.client.post
    response = self.client.post(...)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code,302)
    # .. and the rest
```